# RXJS make an observable dispatch after another (not concat)

Tags: redux, rxjs, observable, redux-observable

I am using redux, redux-observable in react.

I have the following

```
const goToItemEpic = (action$, state$): Observable<any> => action$.pipe(
    ofType(ItemsDetailsActions.goToItem),
    concatMap((action: {payload: {projectId: string; datastoreId: string; itemId: string}}) =>
        of(ProjectActions.setCurrentProjectId({projectId: action.payload.projectId})).pipe(
            delay(1000),
            switchMap(() => {
                return [
                    DatastoreActions.setCurrentDatastoreId({datastoreId: action.payload.datastoreId}),
                    ItemsActions.setCurrentItemId({ itemId: action.payload.itemId })
                ];
            })
        )
    )
);
```

Basically, I would like to dispatch `setCurrentProjectId` then wait for some time, and then dispatch 
`setCurrentDatastoreId` and `setCurrentItemId`

I face two problems :

1) The current code delay `setCurrentDatastoreId` and `setCurrentItemId` but do not execute `setCurrentProjectId`, why ?

2) Here the delay is an hardcoded 1000ms. but I would like to delay based on another observable execution `getDatastoresSuccess`

so the it would be

```
execute => setCurrentProjectId
waitFor => getDatastoresSuccess
execute => setCurrentDatastoreId
execute => setCurrentItemId
```

How do I manage to do that in redux-observable?

EDIT :

```
const goToItemEpic = (action$, state$): Observable<any> => action$.pipe(
    ofType(ItemsDetailsActions.goToItem),
    concatMap((action: {payload: {projectId: string; datastoreId: string; itemId: string}}) =>
        concat(
            ProjectActions.setCurrentProjectId({projectId: action.payload.projectId}),
            action$.pipe(
                ofType(DatastoreActions.getDatastoresSuccess),
                first(),
                switchMap(() => of(
                    DatastoreActions.setCurrentDatastoreId({datastoreId: action.payload.datastoreId}),
                    ItemsActions.setCurrentItemId({ itemId: action.payload.itemId })
                ))
            )
        )
    )
);
```

> subscribeTo.js:23 Uncaught TypeError: You provided an invalid object
>   where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise,
>   Array, or Iterable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that by using `action$.pipe` again to wait for the required action:

```
const goToItemEpic = (action$, state$): Observable<any> => action$.pipe(
    ofType(ItemsDetailsActions.goToItem),
    concatMap((action: {payload: {projectId: string; datastoreId: string; itemId: string}}) =>
        concat(
            of(ProjectActions.setCurrentProjectId({projectId: action.payload.projectId})),
            action$.pipe(
                ofType(ItemsDetailsActions.getDatastoresSuccess),
                first(),
                switchMap(() => of(
                    DatastoreActions.setCurrentDatastoreId({datastoreId: action.payload.datastoreId}),
                    ItemsActions.setCurrentItemId({ itemId: action.payload.itemId })
                )
            })
```

So in the `concat` you first emit the `ProjectActions.setCurrentProjectId` action and after that wait for the `first()` action of type `getDatastoresSuccess` and map this to `setCurrentDatastoreId` and `setCurrentItemId`

The answer to your question 1) is that `setCurrentProjectId` is used as the (ignored) input of `switchMap`, which is then mapped to  `setCurrentDatastoreId` and `setCurrentItemId`

Comment: Thanks for your reply and explanation, I understand question 1 now. I tried your code but got an error (you can see in the edit of the main post). But the logic is the one you describe. I'll try to find a fix for it. thanks

Comment: Sorry, I missed an `of` for `setCurrentProjectId`, that transforms the `action` into an `Observable<Action>`. I've updated my code.

Comment: oh right, I didn't notice too, ok it work great, thank you